# Почему функция дает разный результат

Tags: javascript

```js
var d = {};

function bind(f, arg1) {

  return function() {
    var start = performance.now();

    var func = f.apply(this, arguments)

    if (!d[arg1]) {
      d[arg1] = 0;
    }
    d[arg1] += performance.now() - start;
    return func
  }
}

var fibonacci = function f(n) {
  return (n > 2) ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : 1;
}

var fibonacci = bind(fibonacci, "fibo");

console.log(fibonacci(10)); // 55
console.log(d.fibo + ' мс ');
```

```js
var d = {};

function bind(f, arg1) {

  return function() {
    var start = performance.now();

    var func = f.apply(this, arguments)

    if (!d[arg1]) {
      d[arg1] = 0;
    }
    d[arg1] += performance.now() - start;
    return func
  }
}

var fibonacci = function f(n) {
  return (n > 2) ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : 1;
}

var q = bind(fibonacci, "fibo");

console.log(q(10)); // 55
console.log(d.fibo + ' мс ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в первом примере:

```
var fibonacci = bind(fibonacci, "fibo");
```

а во втором:

```
var q = bind(fibonacci, "fibo");
```

Измените во втором примере

```
console.log(fibonacci(10)); // 55
```

на

```
console.log(q(10)); // 55
```

---

> получается функцию
>
> ```
> var fibonacci = function f(n) { return (n > 2) ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : 1; }
> ```
>
> мы переписали а как тогда мы получаем результат ?

Результат мы получаем, потому что замыкание, созданное внутри `bind`, содержит ссылку на старую функцию `fibonacci`, которую мы туда передали.

Comment: в первом примере var fibonacci = bind(fibonacci, "fibo"); перепишет функцию var fibonacci = function f(n) {
  return (n > 2) ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : 1;
} ?

Comment: @user344279 - да

Comment: получается функцию var fibonacci = function f(n) {
  return (n > 2) ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : 1;
}  мы переписали а как тогда мы получаем результат ?

Comment: @user344279 Результат мы получаем, потому что замыкание, созданное внутри `bind`, содержит ссылку на старую функцию `fibonacci `, которую мы туда передали.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003388/reference-type-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-js можете посмотреть ?